# Hamilton circuit theorem explanation

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

I'm studying graph theory and while looking at Hamilton curcuit examples, one thing struck me.

[image: using Grinberg's theorem]

I don't know where |r6 - r'6| >= 2 came from... i get where this is going until that specific part. What am I missing?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Theorem 3 refers to Grinberg's theorem, fyi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point is that $r_6$ and $r'_6$ have a sum equal to $6$, therefore they are either both even or both odd, and therefore their absolute difference, if not zero, has to be at least $2$.